# Set label color for swipe on Android RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I created a `RecyclerView` with customized swipe draw functionality.
Everything works fine, except of the color of the swipe label.

Question: How can I change the color of the displayed label (not the background).

I use the following code in my activity `onChildDraw` method:

```
new RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator.Builder(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
  .addSwipeRightBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.co  lor.deleteRecyclerViewItem))
  .addSwipeRightActionIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_archive_24)
  .addSwipeRightLabel(viewHolder.itemView.getContext().getString(R.string.archive))
  .addSwipeLeftBackgroundColor(colorPrimary)
  .addSwipeLeftLabel(viewHolder.itemView.getContext().getString(R.string.menu))
  .create()
  .decorate();

super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
```

Everything I found was only about the background.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
.setSwipeLeftLabelColor(your_color)
```

Check customizing section.
https://github.com/xabaras/RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator#customizing